# How do you install Oracle on Linux when you get the error "ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist"?

Tags: centos, software-installation, shared-memory, oracle

I am installing Oracle 11 on CentOS 7.2.  I have installed it before on servers with less RAM.

I get this error:

> ORA-01034: ORACLE not available ORA-27101: shared memory realm does
>   not exist

The host name appears in the /etc/hosts file.  There is plenty of RAM and free disk space.  I have never been able to install it on this server.  But CentOS servers with less RAM accept the installation without a problem.  What am I doing wrong?

I set the shmmax value to be significantly higher than it was set to.  I did what I had to do to get it be persistent.  That is, after a reboot, the value I set it to was still there.  But the problem with the Oracle installation remains, and after the installation attempt, the shmmax value is reverted to its original value.

Comment: I don't know anything about oracle, however a quick search showed it could possibly be the instance hasn't started or an incorrectly set environmental vars [read this](http://www.vitalsofttech.com/ora-27101-shared-memory-realm-does-not-exist/) [and this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:670632200346093489)

Comment: The first link did not help me.  I tried ps -ef | grep smon.   This command returned nothing.  The second link did not help me because I cannot enter the database.  The database has never been up.  $ORACLE_HOME and $ORACLE_SID are not assigned.  I manually assigned $ORACLE_HOME but I had the same problem when I began the installation.  Plus somewhere during the installation $ORACLE_HOME becomes unassigned.  I do not know what to assign $ORACLE_SID to as there is no smon process running.  How do I install Oracle?  I keep getting the error message that I posted in the original posting.